# Cakephp 2+ Image Resize and Crop while uploading the image

Tags: image, cakephp, resize, crop

Hi i need to implement image resize and crop the image while uploading to the server. Please help me out.

Comment: please try  https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

Comment: https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage for 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins doing exactly what you want to:

1. a component https://github.com/angelitomg/QimageComponent you have to actively trigger in your controller
2. a behaviour https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload which allows you to implement the resizing for a hole model(action independent) with a simple actsAs

The second one is developed by josegonzalez who is really active in #cakephp irc and the whole cakephp development... so this is most likely the better choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the image upload behavior

https://github.com/cakecoded/image-upload-behavior/blob/master/app/Model/Behavior/ImageUploadBehavior.php